# Adding the sum of two randomly generated numbers (using arrays)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, random, sum

```
class Program
{
    const int ROLLS = 51;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int sum = 0;
        int[] dice1 = new int[ROLLS];
        int[] dice2 = new int[ROLLS];

        for (int roll = 0; roll <= 50; roll++)
        {
            dice1[roll] = GenerateNum(r);
            dice2[roll] = GenerateNum(r);
            Console.WriteLine("ROLL{0}: {1} + {2} = sum goes here", roll+1, dice1[roll]+1, dice2[roll]+1);
        }
    }

    static int GenerateNum (Random r)
    {
        return r.Next(1, 7);
    }
  }
}
```

So what I have is two arrays to store two different int values that are randomly generated and what I am trying to achieve is the sum of these two randomly generated int values.

Upon execution it should display:
Roll 1: (random number) + (random number) = (sum of the two random numbers)

Comment: What's the issue? Why don't you simply add {3} instead of "sum goes here" and compute the value to pass it in?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("ROLL{0}: {1} + {2} = {3}", roll+1, dice1[roll], dice2[roll], sum);

Comment: @kailanjian I understand that but it was calculating the sum of the two random numbers that I cannot get right.

Comment: @JK. he was getting wrong results due to the additional `+1`'s when spitting out the string in the console (which I shamelessly copy-pasted but @JleruOHeP spotted) - if anything, I guess he was asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the two together and store them in `sum`. Then present `sum` in the same manner you have presented the rest of the values in the output of the console:

```
dice1[roll] = GenerateNum(r);
dice2[roll] = GenerateNum(r);
sum = dice1[roll] + dice2[roll];
Console.WriteLine("ROLL{0}: {1} + {2} = {3}", roll + 1, dice1[roll], dice2[roll], sum);
```

Comment: sum is declared outside of the loop;

and probably you wont need "+1" for dices if you want d6: 
sum = dice1[roll] + dice2[roll];
Console.WriteLine("ROLL{0}: {1} + {2} = {3}", roll + 1, dice1[roll], dice2[roll], sum);